# Error while trying to set style with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web

```
var d = document;
div = d.body.appendChild(d.createElement("DIV"));
div.id = "hi";
div.innerHTML = "Hello World";

cssStyle = ["fontFamily", "fontStyle"];
cssAn = ["Arial", "italic"];

div.style.cssStyle[0] = cssAn[0];
```

It does not set the style. Instead it returns an error stating "Cannot set property 0 of undefined". What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this site. I don't even know how to do that...

Comment: The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) would be a good start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want:

```
div.style[cssStyle[0]] = cssAn[0];
```

Answer (score 6):

`cssStyle` is not a property of `div.style.`  You want:

```
div.style[cssStyle[0]] = cssAn[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not Javascript related — it's a general programming principle.

You have a variable `cssStyle` that contains `"fontFamily"` and `"fontStyle"`.

Accessing the property `cssStyle` of `div.style` is in no way related to the variable `cssStyle`.

You need to `div.style[cssStyle[0]] = cssAn[0]`.

EDIT:

Additionally, if you want all properties whose names are in `cssStyles` and corresponding values in `cssAn` to be set on `div`, then, assuming `cssStyle` and `cssAn` have the same number of elements, you can:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cssStyle.length; i += 1) {
    var name = cssStyle[i];
    var value = cssAn[i];
    div.style[name] = value;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you should rename `cssStyle` to `styleAttrs` and `cssAn` to `styleValues` to signify that both are arrays. Also, if you want to be correct, CSS means the actual .css files or inline style sheets in the HTML file. Styles that you assign in your JS code (or directly using a `style="..."` HTML attribute) are, well, just styles.